# Calculating heights and adding to a variable

Tags: jquery

Good Day

I have the following function that calculates the height of each div and adds it to a variable, but it is not working:

JS:

```
$('#latestInner, #make, #models').each(function() {
    var i = 0;
    var h = $(this).outerHeight();
    i = i + h;
});
alert(i);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="latestInner"></div>
<div id="make"></div>
<div id="models"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#models {height: 100px; background: red;}
#latestInner {height: 200px; background: green;}
#make {height: 150px; background: blue;}
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/uwsJH/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem was scoping.

Try this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/uwsJH/9/

```
i=0;
$('#latestInner, #make, #models').each(function() {
   // var i = 0; <--- wrong scope
    var h = $(this).outerHeight();
    i = i + h;
});
alert(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because i is a local variable.Try i = 0 ,instead var i =0

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
var i = 0;
$('#latestInner, #make, #models').each(function() {

var h = $(this).css("height");
i = i + h;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to initialize the `var i` at each time... You can do it this way :

```
var i = 0;
$('#latestInner, #make, #models').each(function() {

    var h = $(this).outerHeight();
    i = i + h;
    //Or simply
    i = i + $(this).outerHeight();
});
alert(i);
```